# Css to select box in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, css-selectors

My select-box is getting different spacings in Chrome and Firefox

In Chrome the select options stick together .. and in Firefox it gives a small spacing between them... How do I make this spacing equal without using Javascript?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How CSS Increasing line spacing between select box elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451570/how-css-increasing-line-spacing-between-select-box-elements)

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: My code is empy

Answer (score 0):

just use normalize.css before your own css link

e.g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="your_own_stylesheet.css">
```